# Which operating mechanisms are studied is

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical structure of the bold part? How can it be paraphrase more easily (or understandably) for beginners?
This often involves the search for secular mediator and moderator variables that may influence or determine the relationship between religiosity and mental health. **Which operating mechanisms are studied** is an issue that dovetails with the discussions of measurement and of methodology presented by Hill (Chapter 3, this volume) and by Hood and Belzen (Chapter 4, this volume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Which operating mechanism are studied" is an embedded question, functioning as the subject of "is an issue".

It could be clarified as "The question of which operating mechanisms are studied, is an issue..." [Some authorities would object to the comma in this, but I think it makes it clearer].